# how to define URL path in web develpoment

Tags: python, flask

I am developing an app which has a hierarchy of course, chapter, and a lesson.
One course contains none of a chapter & one chapter contains multiple lessons. So I have defined the below mentioned URL so I just want your guys' suggestion if it needs some changes.

/courses

/courses/<:course_id>

/chapter/<:course_id>

/chapter/<:course_id>/<:chapter_id>

/lesson/<:course_id>/<:chapter_id>

/lesson/<:course_id>/<:chapter_id>/<:lesson_id>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want hierarchical URLs, I would use this:

```
/courses/
/courses/<:course_id>
/courses/<:course_id>/chapters/
/courses/<:course_id>/chapters/<:chapter_id>
/courses/<:course_id>/chapters/<:chapter_id>/lessons/
/courses/<:course_id>/chapters/<:chapter_id>/lessons/<:lesson_id>
```

Alternatively, you could go with something like this:

```
/courses
/courses/<:course_id>
/courses/<:course_id>/chapters/
/chapters/<:chapter_id>
/chapters/<:chapter_id>/lessons/
/lessons/<:lesson_id>
```

Depending on your requirements, you could just return the essential information about the nested resources and reference the full resource, e.g. like this:

```
GET /courses/123

{
    'title': 'My course',
    ...
    'chapters': [{
        'url': '/chapters/456'
        'title': 'Chapter 1'
    }]
}
```

Comment: Thanx for suggestion.